# I need help understanding the intuition behind a solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Suppose that $$x + y + z = 203.$$ What would be the maximum value of $$x + (xy)^{1/2} + (xyz)^{1/3}?$$

The solution is to assume that

$$\frac43\cdot (x+y+z)\ge x+(xy)^{1/2}+(xyz)^{1/3}$$ and prove it with AM-GM inequality. I was just wondering how would one come up with that assumption normally? And if there's a general formula for larger cases.

Comment: The solution isn't to "assume" that inequality. The solution is to figure that out, by trying out various coefficients. For example, one can say that $ x + \sqrt{xy} + \sqrt[3]{xyz} \leq x + (x+y)/2 + (x+y+z)/3$, but that doesn't relate well to the condition of $x+y+z = 203$. So, we try something else, like say $\sqrt{xy} \leq (x/2 + 2y)/2$ and $ \sqrt[3]{xyz} \leq (x/4 + y + 4z)/3$ till we can get the RHS to be like $ A ( x+y+z) = 203A$ while ensuring that equality holds throughout. It's also known as the "method of unknown coefficients".

Comment: Thank you, I'll read up on that method